# Why use commands in WPF and not event handlers

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using `WPF` like a year ago and `MVVM`, I guess not full, because I don't use Commands,. and till now I really did all I need without commands and it works fine, but the most important thing to me, its clear and short, the theory of `MVVM` says `no code behind`, but, why got complicated with 1000 classes, one for each button or event?

I really don´t see the gain. Is this only conceptual or there is more ?

Comment: `The theory of MVVM says no code behind` nope `why got complicated with 1000 classes, one for each button or event` noooope.  You should probably get a book about MVVM in WPF.

Comment: Think about porting your application to a windows phone. Your Vm can be taken to wp application also.  Mvvm is pattern to separate the code to achieve loosely coupling. But you can build without MVVM.  All you Vm is testable and your code behind is quite hard to test. Magic of binding and validation in the model are quite good feature to concentrate on the core developement

Comment: First thing that came to my mind is: If you dont use Commands you dont do mvvm... And you dont have to have one command per button if you do a proper design

Comment: ok, I know not using commands means not a full mvvm, but  where is the gain? what  can I do with commands and not with eventHandlers,. that is what I trying to understand, because I rather a simple code than a complex code, and as I see using a eventhandler as a caller for a ViewModel method is really simple, just one line, against a full class only for do the same method's call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to explain why commands are useful.

In MVVM, the View developers (designers) are supposed to do only things that affect how the program looks like, while ViewModel developers (programmers) would only care about the behavior.

Imagine you have a form with a submit button. If the form is not submitted to the database(for example), it is the programmer's problem; no one would blame the designer. However, using event means that everything is done at the View side.

This is where Command comes to the rescue. It allows the programmers to do the logic, thereafter wait for the designer to bind to it. Programmers can do unit testing without the design (View), and proudly tell people that it works. If it breaks, that means the designer did not bind to it correctly.

Of course, I believe there are many people here who would be doing everything alone. In this case, the usefulness of MVVM would be reduced. However do note when you totally remove all views from the VS project, your ViewModel is going to compile and be fully functional - except that there is no GUI, and that it can receive no user inputs. Typically, most of the project requirements are behavioral, so if your ViewModel are working, then you would have met most of the requirements.

Lastly, I would want to point out that, it is okay to have code-behind - as long as it is purely only affecting how things are looking, and not affecting behaviour. Of course, most perfectionist would want to have zero code-behind, but in some cases this isn't always possible.

Comment: Thanks foryour answer, I guess if that's the only reason its most useful in a team and the goal of this is to separate rols in the team. but if the project is small and one developer is perfectly valid  use event handlers  to call methods in the ViewModel that make all the logic, some like this:
`private void Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
       VM myVM=(VM)this.DataContext;
       myVM.Save();
  }`
I know that break the concept of mvvm, a little bit, but... is not bad at all right? I mean the view only calls a method , doesn't do any logic, just a call

Comment: @KillemAll Yeah, to certain extent, when you are soloing the whole project, MVVM would not be exactly very useful. I am also new to C#/WPF/MVVM (several months experience), and I have/am soloing projects as well. So far, I haven't felt how much of a difference MVVM have made (other than the fact that I need to think very hard how to make sure I don't break the MVVM concept xD).

Comment: LOL !! I agree with you about that is hard not break MVVM. In my case I really like the databinding and the concept of separate rols. the only part that I'm not really convinced, the commands,..  to much code for calling methods of the viewmodel  :P lol

Answer (score 4):

Your question is too broad to be answered in a line. But I am answering it since I have been working with MVVM for quite a long time by now and also have worked in WPF without MVVM also.

As the comment points out your words : **The theory of MVVM says no code behind nope why got complicated with 1000 classes, one for each button or event**.

These are not true actually. Because there are lot of benefits of using MVVM and that is the reason why this question is too broad.

I am surprised to hear that you haven't used **Commands** till now and you're using MVVM. Because command is a major part of MVVM. The main benefit of using MVVM is that it really helps us to

1. **Separate the view and model**. Nobody wants their codebehind(YourPage.xaml.cs) to contain all data related code, data manipulations, designs and also setting the user control data and so on. It will make the situation worse if you want to fix a bug in your code or someone wants to review it. In MVVM, you can have a clean code behind. There is not much difference between an event handler and command. But if you want to update several views over a button click, MVVM could handle it very neatly and easily.
2. **Databinding** ensures better maintainability and readability. Instead of setting TextBox1.Text = "Hello World", you could bind the Text property to a view model property and let it update each time the model changes. This is really a great thing to have. Who wants to write code for updating the view each time model changes. Think how many lines of code are saved now. Everything is done by databinding. If you want to change 10 textboxes content when a button is clicked, binding will be very handy. Hence it reduces **Tight Coupling**.
3. **Testability** : The developers can create unit tests for the view model and the model without using the view. The unit tests for the view model can exercise exactly the same functionality as used by the view. Also many developers can work with the same product at the same time, since a large view could be split into smaller views and work could be divided very easily.

Comment: Hi, I may be wrong, but I 'm use to use the code behind just for call methods of the viewmodel, I do all the databinding in the xaml, never do something like textbox1.text="hello" , so my codebehind is really clear and small  just a few lines by event handler. I've saw commands but it is a lot of code  to do a simple methos call , thats why I am asking here, why should I use commands? if calling VM's methods in event handlers is so easy and clear.

Comment: Lol.  You're still asking the same question after so much explanation.  Did you read my answer completely?  Your code behind has only few lines since your project is not large scale.  Large scale projects might have upto 2k lines of code behind and obviously becomes difficult to manage or to maintain them. So MVVM and commands.  It's upto you actually.  If you feel event handler is good for your project,  then it is perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm also thinking the `ICommand` is an unusefully thing,  I'm a web dev and do a little WPF/Xamarin work, I think the Command itself is just a  delegate,  but the Command is a class, that sepreate from the VM, that mean u had to pass ur method to the command class to let the Command know ur VM property,  I'm using Vue&Angular a lot, and so far I can say, to use Command and giveup the power that the event can provide is foolish, for example:  click/double-click handle , in Vue there only method , and the view of Vue just "bind" to the VM's method, so we can use any event as we want